# Why doesn't the mobile version of my website take updates?

Tags: mobile

Thanks in advance for your assistance with this!

The site I am having trouble with is `http://www.howtoimportkit.com`

I have made several updates to the site that show up fine on desktop, but are not going through to the mobile version. If you check the site on a mobile emulator on a desktop the changes come through, but on an actual phone they do not.

I am using the responsive theme Zerif Lite and NO cache plugins.

I have tried clearing cache on all of my mobile browsers, tried on different phones that have never visited the site before, tried on Wifi and Cell Data (in case my wifi router was somehow caching) and nothing seems to work.

I have tried installing different cache plugins, then using the "delete cache" option, then uninstalling and deleting the plugins via Wordpress and FTP.

I don't think my host has a separate cache, because I use Dreamhost and not Dreampress (which has its own cache system).

Some examples of changes not going through:
-Desktop: price at bottom is on sale for $35
-Mobile: price stuck at $99

-Desktop: no longer lists free shipping as a bonus
-Mobile: still shows free shipping

-Desktop: "Contact and FAQ" page has no language regarding snail mail shipping
-Mobile: "Contact and FAQ" page stuck with old language

Thanks again for any help you can provide! I have tried many different things and various other forums/searches and have spent hours on this problem without a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I just checked your site both on both mobile emulator of chrome and on my mobile ios phone and I don't see the changes you are mentioning.  I am not sure how you are determining whether you are on mobile or not, because you have not shown any code.

A great PHP solution that I use to determine whether I am on mobile on my site is MobileDetect (http://mobiledetect.net/).

For example:

```
if( $detect->isMobile()){
    echo'34.99';
}
else{
    echo'99.99';
}
```

Anyway, I hope that helpls

Comment: When you say you don't see the changes, do you mean, for example, that the price in desktop ($35) is showing as the same price on your mobile ios phone?

Comment: Yes I saw the same price.  Sorry for the late reply.  I see 99.99 for both mobile and desktop

Comment: lol get downvoted?

Comment: You don't specify how your website determines whether you are on mobile nor do you provide any code

Comment: Update: I reached out to Dreamhost as well. They came back w: "Ok so I pulled up your site howtoimportkit.com on my mobile device and it
showed the $99 dollar price. However I had a few other co workers pull up
the site on their phone and it showed $35. So it seems like half the time
it is working correctly and the other half the time it's not.

Can you let me know what you are using for the mobile version of your
site? There is various plugins and themes available that have mobile
features built into them and I think one of those features might have a
bug or something like that."

Comment: Since the theme I am using is responsive (Zerif Lite) either the theme itself or whatever the base code in Wordpress is what is being used to determine whether to render mobile or desktop version of the site

Comment: and sorry someone downvoted you. it wasn't me, my account is too new to downvote or upvote

Comment: I recommend checking to see if its a browser specific problem.  Try looking at various browsers and see what comes up.  That may help you to single out the issue.  I would also try deactivating all plugins and seeing if that resolves the issue as well.  Its possible one of your plugins might be causing the issue.

Comment: I tried updating all plugins to see if that rectified it but unfortunately I see the same issue. So far have also encountered the issue on iOS Safari and iOS Firefox. Will keep plugging away. thanks for your replies!

Comment: Yeah also try deactivating, not just updating.

Comment: hey man I fixed it! it was a very weird specific DNS error regarding ip 6 vs p 4. I would have had no idea without my host looking into it. Now to figure out why this menu won't stay open on mobile....